# Django FieldError at / Unknown field(s) (type) specified for Model

Tags: django

I have a FieldError at / Unknown field(s) (type) specified for Model

My model:

```
class SocialNetwork(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name='social_networks')
    handle = models.CharField(max_length =50)
    types = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices = SOCNET_TYPES)
    public_visible = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    contact_visible = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @property
    def url(self):
        prefixes = social_net_prefixes
        prefix = getattr(settings, '%s_PREFIX' % self.type.upper(), prefixes[self.type])
        return '%s%s' % (prefix, self.handle)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s: %s" % (self.contact.first_name, self.type, self.handle)
```

my formModel:

```
class SocialNetworkForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SocialNetwork
        fields = ('handle', 'type', 'public_visible', 'contact_visible')
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

In forms change filed:

```
'type' into 'types'
```